# Need help on list comprhensions. How to use several exclusions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So what I'm looking for is the correct way to search a list and filter the items based on several other lists.

```
imageList = ['green_D.jpg', 'red_D.gif', 'orange_R.jpg', 'black_S.gif', 'folder_A', 'folder_B']
included_extensions = ['jpg', 'bmp', 'png', 'gif']
excluded_textures = ['_R.', '_A.', '_S.']
```

I want to then iterate over my **imageList** and filter only images using **incuded_extensions** and then filter out all texture abbreviations specified in **excluded_textures**.

My failed code:

```
newImageList = [ (img for img in imageList) if (tex for tex in excluded_textures) not in img and any(img.endswith(ext) in img for ext in included_extensions)]
```

The result should then only contain

```
newImageList = ['green_D.jpg', 'red_D.gif']
```

Comment: `[i for i in imageList if any(ext in i for ext in included) and not any(ext in i for ext in excluded)]`?

Comment: You would be better off starting by writing this as standard nested loops, *then* trying to compose the list comprehension from that (if you still feel you need to).

Comment: By the way, just because something *can* be written as a list comprehension doesn't mean it *should* be written as a list comprehension. Readability counts!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I'd use a loop -- Cramming it all into a single list-comprehension is going to make the code harder to understand which isn't really what you want...:

```
imageList = ['green_D.jpg', 'red_D.gif', 'orange_R.jpg', 'black_S.gif', 'folder_A', 'folder_B']
included_extensions = ('jpg', 'bmp', 'png', 'gif')  # Note, tuple.
excluded_textures = ('_R.', '_A.', '_S.')

newImageList = []
for img in imageList:
    # If the extension isn't included, just continue the loop.
    if not img.endswith(included_extensions):  # str.endswith accepts tuple, but not list (see change above).
        continue

    # Split off the extension so we can test the excluded_textures
    base, _ = os.path.splitext(img)
    # If the image's base ends with an excluded texture, just continue the loop.
    if (base + '.').endswith(excluded_textures):
        continue

    # The image has passed all of the validation we threw at it.  Add
    # it to the newImageList.
    newImageList.append(img)
```

I've just tested it and this code gives the correct output.

Comment: Can you explain why you changed the __included_extensions__ from `list` to `tuple`? Is this related to speed?

Comment: Upvote for clean code.. Can you explain how the last if statement works?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis -- `str.startswith` and `str.endswith` accept `tuple` (but not `list`).

Comment: @SwadhikarC -- Happy to ... Which statement are you referring to?

Comment: This part   base, _ = os.splitext(imgList)
    if img.endswith(base + '.'):

Comment: @Ev.Kounis -- Yeah, there were a couple typos in there ... argh. :-/

Comment: @SwadhikarC -- Oops.  Yeah, definitely wasn't right.  It's apparently still too early in the morning :-).  I've commented the code now.  Let me know if it is any clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the due diligence!

Answer (score 1):

```
imageList = ['green_D.jpg', 'red_D.gif', 'orange_R.jpg', 'black_S.gif', 'folder_A', 'folder_B']
included_extensions = ['jpg', 'bmp', 'png', 'gif']
excluded_textures = ['_R.', '_A.', '_S.']

print filter(lambda x:x[-3:] in included_extensions and x[-6:-3] not in excluded_textures,imageList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [16]: new_list = [img for img in imageList if any(img.endswith(good_ext) for 
    ...: good_ext in included_extensions) and not any(bad_tex in img for bad_tex
    ...:  in excluded_textures)]

In [17]: new_list
Out[17]: ['green_D.jpg', 'red_D.gif']
```

If you really want to do this with list comprehension here's how. (Not very readable)

Comment: FWIW, `any(img.endswith(good_ext) for good_ext in included_extensions)` can be written as `img.endswith(tuple(included_extensions))` and if `included_extensions` is a `tuple` to being with then it's definitely simpler to write.

Comment: Thank you so much! Once again stack overflow comes to the rescue!